# Cypress automation for status check

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm trying to automate the application to check the status for 1000 employees and Below if the code. First it tries to open and next when it tries to hit another time the pop-up comes so, the test fails. But I have to open in 1000 tabs to check the status. Is there any way to do it. For example:

```javascript
it('check status functionaltiy', function () {
    cy.visit('https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do')

    var genArr = Array.from({length:1000},(v,k)=>k+1)
    cy.wrap(genArr).each((index) => {
      cy.get('input[type="text"]')
      .type(`IOE1234567${index}`)
      cy.log(`IOE1234567${index}`,'ppppppppp')
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();
    })    
})
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to stub your newly opened tab? I don't see any status checking, one iteration of your test stops on clicking submit button which invokes opening a new tab I guess, correct me if I'm wrong. If so, just stub opening a new tab and go further through the loop

Comment: I'm learning cypress and I dont know how to open the new tab. I'll check but for each tab will it check?

Comment: I thought if you click the submit button your new tab opens automatically. Is it right?

Comment: No it didnt .. the pop-up comes and its unable to test the next one

Comment: To prevent popup from opening, you should use cy.stub function the following way:  cy.window().then((win) => { cy.stub(win, 'open').as('Open'); }); somewhere before opening it (I usually use it in the beginning of helper functions which clicks on the button)

Comment: Okay, I tried something like this  cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();
      cy.get("#ui-id-1")
        .invoke('text')               
        .should('eq', 'Data Entry Errors')                
        .then(() => {
          cy.get('.ui-dialog-buttonset').click();
        })
    }) but thing is sometimes its failing after 20 attemtps

Comment: Please update your question with the screenshot and/or text of error which you get